# Why I can't manipulate rows which are loaded from external HTML file using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html-table, row

I got one HTML file containing a table:

src.Html:

```
<table id="all">
  <tr>
    <th>Row 1</th>
    <td>Content 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Row 2</th>
    <td>Content 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Row 3</th>
    <td>Content 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And here is my code:

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    var tempTable = $('<table id="tempTable"></table>');
    tempTable.load('src.Html #all tr');
    console.log(tempTable);    --> it shows content of tempTable

    console.log($(tempTable).find('tr'));   --> it shows []

});
```

it's works, and it prints the content of tempTable.

But when I want to get row based on needs, it shows nothing!
Such as:

```
$(tempTable).find('tr');        --> []
$(tempTable).find('tr').eq(1);  --> []
$('#tempTable tr:eq(2)')        --> []
```

Can anyone tell me why? Is that tempTable not a normal DOM object?

Comment: You need to either `reassign` or `redeclare` the `tempTable` variable as `$('#tempTable')` before you try to use it `as a selector`.

Comment: Is it because it's not in the DOM? Try `$(document.body).append(tempTable);` then see if you can select rows.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I reassign tempTable=$('#tempTable'); and it's still not working:(

Comment: @Jake yes, it cans. But I want save it as a temp variable, then I can fetch rows from it based on needs, to create a new table to show.

Comment: When do you access `tempTable`? Note that the [.load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method takes a callback parameter. Of course the request is asynchronous, hence immediately after the request, the contents won't be available... You don't show enough code to be sure about what exactly you do.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy - if you take `tempTable`, which is a jQuery object containing the (as yet not in the DOM) table, and pass it to the `$()` function as `$(tempTable)`, does that not return another jQuery object containing the same element? That's what [the doco](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/) seems to say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally dislike the [.load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method. I've always been struggling with it. I don't even know why [this](http://jsfiddle.net/w7jRW/) example doesn't properly load and display the HTML. However, I did do some testing in there. See for yourself.

Within the callback, it's all fine. The callback is executed after the calls to the same functions outside of the callback. That means your content is loaded after your code, hence you receive empty arrays.

The reason why you still are showed, in the Google Chrome Developer Tool, par example, that temp table has the children, is that you have a reference to a DOM object. I believe the difference is that the JavaScript scope is different from the DOM scope. Unlike pure JavaScript objects, every reference I've so far had to a DOM object is automatically updated. See in [this](http://jsfiddle.net/w7jRW/1/) revision. Both references to the same table show that the third row has a different content although they are called at different times.

Concluding, all you need is a ***callback handler***.

*Edit:*

Forget about why it wouldn't show the contents. Of course it wouldn't, I never updated them.

Comment: it's work when I put it all in [.load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) 's callback function. But I can't manipulate Table outside it. So I think it's some kind of scope issue.

Comment: @yyc1217 It is not a scope issue. As I said, the problem is due to how JavaScript references DOM objects. As you can see in my fiddles, the callback is called after whatever comes after the request. That means despite how fast your server might be, there still is a delay of at least a fraction of a millisecond, enough to run through the other code before the callback is invoked. By the time you attempt to access the code outside the callback, your HTML has not been loaded yet.

Comment: So it's all due to JavaScript is asynchronous. I will keep it in mind! Thank you:)

Answer (score 0):

Simply use ***callback*** of [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load) function:

```
tempTable.load('src.Html #all tr', function() {
  $(tempTable).find('tr');
});
```

Comment: I was quicker with a more in-depth explanation. :P

Comment: Thank you:) It's working when I put it all in callback function.